# Why /tmp is bound in /tmp ? How can I remove this bound

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, fstab, fuse

In Scientific Linux 6, a clone of RHEL6, I have the following **mtab** file:

```
/dev/sda2 / ext4 rw 0 0
proc /proc proc rw 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,gid=5,mode=620 0 0
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs rw,rootcontext="system_u:object_r:tmpfs_t:s0" 0 0
/dev/sda1 /boot ext4 rw 0 0
none /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw 0 0
/tmp /tmp none rw,bind 0 0
/var/tmp /var/tmp none rw,bind 0 0
/home /home none rw,bind 0 0
sunrpc /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs rpc_pipefs rw 0 0
gvfs-fuse-daemon /root/.gvfs fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0
```

the content of **fstab** is

```
enter code here
#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Tue Apr 21 14:07:48 2020
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'       
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
UUID=ce58d311-5f32-4da6-9f96-ca9353dc421c /                       ext4    defaults        1 1
UUID=1e4e79e3-3317-4c50-8880-c25d6a03f4a4 /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
UUID=eec379ab-8116-46ef-b93b-9bdcd0ab65e2 swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
```

and the output of **mount** command is:

```
/dev/sda2 on / type ext4 (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,rootcontext="system_u:object_r:tmpfs_t:s0")
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext4 (rw)
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw)
/tmp on /tmp type none (rw,bind)
/var/tmp on /var/tmp type none (rw,bind)
/home on /home type none (rw,bind)
sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /root/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev)
```

Why /tmp is bound on /tmp ? (also /home on /home, /var/tmp on /var/tmp)

How can I remove this bound and put /tmp as common directory under / ?

I need this because I have an old executable which use the instruction 
rename and it give me the following error

*EXDEV  oldpath  and  newpath  are  not on the same mounted file system.  (Linux permits a file system to be mounted at multiple points, but rename() does not work across different
mount points, even if the same file system is mounted on both.)*

when it try to rename a file with oldpath int /tmp and newpath under a subdirectory of / .

Comment: I can't repro on a vanilla SL 6.8 / CentOS 6. No bind mounts were present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have run

chkconfig sandbox off

Then reboot.

As suggested by Jose Marques.